# Effective regex for multiple strings with characters and numbers

Tags: python, regex

Hi I'm new to Python and RegEx. I'm experimenting with both and trying to get a single regular expression to extract the data from a user but I expect different inputs considering typos etc. So in the following code I'm randomly selecting some type  of strings that I expect a user to give to give you an example how they may type in the data. I'm only interested in the number that comes before or after USD. For example:

```
ran = random.randint(1, 7)
print str(ran)
if ran == 1:
    examplestring = "This item costs 20 USD contact 9999999"
elif ran == 2:
    examplestring = "This item costs USD 20"
elif ran == 3:
    examplestring = "This item costs 20 U.S.D"
elif ran == 4:
    examplestring = "This item costs 20 usd"
elif ran == 5:
    examplestring = "This item costs 20 Usd call to buy : 954545577"
elif ran == 6:
    examplestring = "This item costs 20USD"
elif ran == 7:
    examplestring = "This item costs usd20"

regex = re.compile(r'\busd|\bu.s.d\b|\bu.s.d.\b', re.I)
examplestring = regex.sub("USD", examplestring)
costs = re.findall(r'\d+.\bUSD\b|\bUSD\b.\d+|\d+USD\b|\bUSD\d+', examplestring)
cost = "".join(str(n) for n in costs[0])
cost = ''.join(x for x in cost if x.isdigit())
print cost + " USD"
```

Using these regular expressions I can get the detail I want which is "20 USD". My question is if I'm doing it the right way and if it is possible to make the code better ?

Comment: You can do all of this with one regex: `(?:(?<=USD|usd)\s*(\d+))|(?:\d+\s*(?=USD|usd|Usd|U.S.D))` but sometimes this is not a good way of doing it because of the complexity of the regex. See an explanation [here](https://regex101.com/r/mH0cC8/1) on how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to do it:

```
regex = re.compile(r'\b(?=[0-9U])(?:[0-9]+\s*U\.?S\.?D|U\.?S\.?D\s*[0-9]+)\b', re.I)

result = [x.strip(' USD.usd') for x in regex.findall(yourstring)]
```

pattern details:

```
\b         # word boundary
(?=[0-9U]) # only here to quickly discard word-boundaries not followed
           # by a digit or the letter U without to test the two branches
           # of the following alternation. You can remove it if you want.

(?:
    [0-9]+\s*U\.?S\.?D # USD after
  |                    # OR
    U\.?S\.?D\s*[0-9]+ # USD before
)
\b
```

Note that spaces and dots are optional for the two branches.

Then the "USD" part of the result is removed with a simple strip. it's more handy (and probably faster) than trying to exclude USD from the match result with lookarounds.

Comment: This works perfectly thank you so much but what if the user makes a typo and gives something like u,s,d instead of u.s.d how do I include the commas ?

Comment: @Cheth_K: It's not possible to handle all the possible typos of the universe, but for your specific question, replace `\.` with `[,.]` and add the comma in the strip character list.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Regex101](https://regex101.com/#python) for more information and explaining the given regex. Especially you should pay attention to groups (like `(\d+)`), because I think that is what you need for extracting a value properly.

Substituting and then search in a this substituted string is somehow messy in my opinion.

```
import re
lines = """This item costs 20 USD
This item costs USD 20
This item costs 20 U.S.D
This item costs 20 usd
This item costs 20 Usd
This item costs 20USD
This item costs usd20"""

# as you can see there are two groups with the price
pattern = re.compile(r"u\.?s\.?d\s*(\d+)|(\d+)\s*u\.?s\.?d", re.I)
# one of the groups must have matched, so I take the non-empty one using `or`operator
print ["{} USD".format(fst or sec) for fst, sec in pattern.findall(lines)]
```

Out:

```
['20 USD', '20 USD', '20 USD', '20 USD', '20 USD', '20 USD', '20 USD']
```

Answer (score 0):

As a very general solution `[0-9]+` would extract the amount only, disregarding other text surrounding it. It focuses on what you need to extract, and not on what to possibly ignore.

Comment: Ok I edited it, the first time I didnt post it properly. The user can also give other inputs like phone numbers. So i have assumed that the number i need always comes either immediately after or before usd.

Comment: Why the downvote? The OP changed the specs after my answer, before that my answer was valid.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a single Regex with groups to extract the values directly instead.  For example "(\d+) *u\.?s\.?d\.?|u\.?s\.?d\.? *(\d+)" can be used to do a search your strings (with ignore case specified) and then, if you get a match, your cost will be in either group 1 or group 2, depending on which variant matched.